# Recollindex skipped directory

Tags: directory, recoll

I have to recoll indexing more than 10000 directories and huge number of files.

My directory structure looks like:

Class1

Class1\Users

Class1\Users\Teachers

Class1\Users\Students

Class2\Users\Teachers

Class2\Users\Students

XXXX\YYYY\Teachers

XXXX\YYYY\Students

...

It is important to don't indexing Students directories. 
Where can I set to skip the Students directories on recoll-gui?
I found recoll manual: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html
and I also found the "skippedPaths" variable, but I don't know the exact format, how can I skipping "Students" directories on the indexing (on recoll-gui).

[recoll-gui settings Screenshot](http://i0.wp.com/imagecdn5.maketecheasier.com/2013/09/recoll-indexing-configuration.png)

Mod:
Unfortunately, there are "Students" directory everywhere, not only under Users directory. For example there is Student directory under Teacher directory.

Skipped Names is not good, because in the Teacher directory there are documents which called "student-names.xls" and indexing may skipped that document also...

Answer (score 1):

In the GUI, go to the indexing configuration section, and click on the + sign for the Skipped Paths section.

This does not open a file selector because you could conceivably have wildcards in there.

Just copy the path for the Students folder *as seen on the Linux machine*. You can probably see an example path in the "Top directories" section as you must have added something in there.

There will be no backslashes in the path, of course.

Ok, second try: I now understand that you have many "Students" directories, maybe a huge number. If this is the case, you should probably use the "Skipped Names" parameter instead. Go to "Indexing parameters" - "Local parameters" and just add "Students" to the "Skipped names" list (globally: no need for anything in the "Customised subtrees" section)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are "Students" directory everywhere, not only under Users directory. For example there is Student directory under Teacher directory.

Skipped Names is not good, because in the Teacher directory there are documents which called "student-names.xls" and indexing may skipped that documents also...